# How to make GridLayout in NativeScript Angular suitable for (potrait/landscape)

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have approx 25 fields to display in one page so I would like to display two or three fields per row.

I have made below layout but is not responsive to the device width (potrait/landscape)

Here is my code, also play link is available [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=AqwG4J).

```
<StackLayout>
    <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto" rows="auto, 25">
        <Label col="0" [colSpan]="1" text="Check 1" class=" h3 m-x-10 m-y-auto"></Label>
        <Switch col="1" [colSpan]="1"> </Switch>
        <Label col="2" [colSpan]="1" text="Check 2" class=" h3 m-x-10 m-y-auto"></Label>
        <Switch col="3" [colSpan]="1"> </Switch>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto" rows="auto, 25">
        <TextField col="0" hint="Branch Code" class=" h3 m-x-10 m-y-auto"></TextField>
        <Label col="1" text="test date" class=" h3 m-x-10 m-y-auto"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto" rows="auto, 25">
        <TextField col="0" hint="Name" class=" h3 m-x-10 m-y-auto"></TextField>
        <TextField col="1" hint="Address" class=" h3 m-x-10 m-y-auto"></TextField>
        <TextField col="2" hint="Mobile" class=" h3 m-x-10 m-y-auto"></TextField>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I trid with `width="60"` somehow works but I want it to responsive width instead of fixed width.

I there a sample workaround for this?

Comment: `auto` will take only required space. You have defined only 3 columns but have 4 elements inside on first grid layout. Do you have at least a screenshot or something of what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't have screen shot but I would like have it like bootstrap responsive.

Comment: All you have to do is split the space properly. Try using `columns="*,*"`, use margin / padding on the Label / TextField for any space in between / around.

Comment: Small peace of code would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=AqwG4J&v=2) you can use. It uses a `GridLayout` that has 17 itmes in 8 rows. I have used `rowspan` and `colspan` as well and it's fully responsive.

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *,*" rows="*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*" width="100%" height="900" backgroundColor="lightgray">

  <Label text="Label 1" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="red"></Label>
  <Switch text="Label 2" row="0" col="1" colSpan="2" backgroundColor="green">
  </Switch>
  <Label text="Label 3" row="1" col="0" rowSpan="2" backgroundColor="blue"></Label>
  <Label text="Label 4" row="1" col="1" backgroundColor="yellow"></Label>
  <Label text="Label 5" row="1" col="2" backgroundColor="orange"></Label>
  <Label text="Label 6" row="2" col="1" backgroundColor="pink"></Label>
  <Label text="Label 7" row="2" col="2" backgroundColor="purple"></Label>

  <TextField text="TextField" row="3" col="1">
  </TextField>
  <Label text="Label 10" row="3" col="2" backgroundColor="purple"></Label>

  <Label text="Label 11" row="4" col="1" backgroundColor="pink"></Label>
  <Label text="Label 12" row="4" col="2" backgroundColor="purple"></Label>

  <TextField text="Label 13" row="5" col="1" backgroundColor="pink">
  </TextField>
  <Label text="Label 14" row="5" col="2" backgroundColor="purple"></Label>

  <Label text="Label 1" row="6" col="0" backgroundColor="red"></Label>
  <Label text="Label 2" row="6" col="1" colSpan="2" backgroundColor="green"></Label>

  <Switch text="Label 1" row="7" col="0" backgroundColor="red">
  </Switch>
  <Label text="Label 2" row="7" col="1" colSpan="2" backgroundColor="green"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```